# An event to listen to for validation of children in a viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-view

I am building a Wizard library for android, whereby I add layouts (which contain other views) to the Wizard.

I need to figure out some sort of event the parent ViewGroup can listen to on its children so these children can be validated. Once validated, the wizard will allow the user to move to the next page.

I have tried listening for the MotionEvent type ACTION_UP. Unfortunately, listening to this on the ViewGroup will fire before the child's state has changed (in other words, it gets called before the child, and so I cannot benefit from the child knowing this).

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

**Update** What I mean by validation is this: Consider a Wizard with two pages

```
+-----------+-----------+
|Page 1     |Page2      |
|------     |-----      |
|Radio Bttn |           |
|EditView   |           |
|           |           |
|           |           |
|       next|           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

The next button of each page starts off as disabled. Before the user can push the next button of page 1 to get to page 2, both the radio button and the editview of page 1 needs to be non-empty. So I need a generic way to determine when the children of page 1 have changed their state. My idea is that when a child's state is changed, I will fire an event that someone will subscribe to via an interface. This event will be along the lines of "ValidateView", and then the user would programmaticly via their own business logic to determine if it is possible to move on to the next page. When this happens the next button of page 1 will be enabled. To note that page 1 can be any generic viewgroup and may contain other views besides the ones that I have presented, that is the reason why I don't want to add listeners on the children, because then to use my Wizard, I would be forced override each children view or else listen to each state change of each view.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by validating the children?

Comment: @Luksprog - I have updated my explanation in the main question above. Hopefully that helps a bit.

Comment: I see what you want to do, but *My idea is that when a child's state is changed, I will fire an event that someone will subscribe to via an interface*, this is the exact definition of a current listener(onClick, onTouch etc), I don't see how you would expect to *see* the state changing. Without custom `Views` or listeners on each view you don't have any hooks to see that the children's state has change.